# C concatenate string with int in loop

Tags: c, string

I'm new to C and am having trouble with strings.  What I would like to do is create a string like "val1, val2, val3" in a loop.

Currently my code looks something like:

```
char tagstr[60] = "";
int k;
int n = 5;
for (k=0; k < n; k++) {
    char temp[10]  = "";
    sprintf(temp, ", val%d", k);
    strcat(tagstr, temp);
}
```

But the output of tagstr is ", val#", where # is some long integer value.  I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with pointers here but I've tried everything I can think of without success... any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: more context, if it helps:

```
int tagsClosed = strlen(pch1) - strcspn(pch1, ")");
do {
    if (curTag.size > 0) {
        // problem section
        char tagstr[60] = "";
        int k;
        for (k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            char temp[10] = "";
            sprintf(temp, ", val%i", temp, k);
            strcat(tagstr, temp);
        }

        // This prints out something like ", val-890132840" x 5 (same number)
        printf ("String is now: %s\n", tagstr);
    }
    curTag = *(curTag.parent);
    tagsClosed--;
} while (tagsClosed > 0);
```

curTag is a struct:

```
typedef struct Tag {
    char * name;
    int size; // number of children
    int tagnum;
    struct Tag* parent;
} Tag;
```

Comment: 1st problem `temp[5]` isn't bug enough to hold ", valk" make it temp[10] or something just to be sure you have enough space.

Comment: whoops, fixed.  Same problem, though.

Comment: The code you've posted is fine (apart from that it doesn't compile). It also has nothing to do with pointers. You'll need to show us your actual code.

Comment: I'm not sure where it's going wrong, then... edited to add more context if that helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `sprintf(temp, ", val%i", temp, k);` adds the value of `temp` (which is actually the address of the first character in the array) to the string, and doesn't add the value of `k` to the string at all. This should be `sprintf(temp, ", val%i", k);`.

You can calculate the amount of space you'd need in advance (including zero terminator):

```
5+1 + 5+1 + 5+1 + 5+1 + 5+1 + 1 = 31 characters
```

Also; using `strcat` is bad (for performance) because you'd be repeatedly searching for the end of the `tagstr` and then copying the new characters to the end. It would be better to keep track of the current end of `tagstr` and store then next group of characters directly at the end with no searching, no temporary string and no copying. For example:

```
void thing(void) {
    char tagstr[60];
    int pos = 0;
    int k;
    int n = 5;

    for (k=0; k < n; k++) {
        pos += sprintf(&tagstr[pos], ", val%d", k);
    }
    printf ("String is now: %s\n", tagstr);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Works for me:**

```
$ gcc -xc - && ./a.out
int main(void) {
        char tagstr[60] = "";
        int k;
        int n = 5;
        for (k=0; k < n; k++) {
            char temp[10]  = "";
            sprintf(temp, ", val%d", k);
            strcat(tagstr, temp);
        }
        printf("[%s]\n", tagstr);
}
[, val0, val1, val2, val3, val4]
```

Unless you're saying the problem is with the initial `", "`..

Comment: Give or take `#include <string.h>` and `#include <stdio.h>`, and I used `<<` and `>>` in place of square brackets, that's the result I got too.

Answer (score 2):

your temp array is too short!
use

```
char temp[16];
```

Comment: Edited to fix this - it still has the same problem, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you decide you don't want the leading comma and blank, you can use a simple variation on the code you showed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char tagstr[60] = "";
    const char *pad = "";
    int k;
    int n = 5;
    for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        char temp[10]  = "";
        snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "%sval%d", pad, k);
        strcat(tagstr, temp);
        pad = ", ";
    }
    printf("tagstr <<%s>>\n", tagstr);
    return 0;
}
```

The output from the program was:

```
tagstr <<val0, val1, val2, val3, val4>>
```

However, your code works correctly for me, albeit with the leading comma and blank.

Answer (score 0):

`temp` isn't long enough to hold the result of your `sprintf`. This is exactly why you should use `snprintf`, `strncat` and other variants of the string functions that take a size parameter, whenever you can.

Comment: Edited to fix this - still has the same problem.